# TextBox Inside ListView WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, textbox

I have a `TextBox` inside my `ListView`.  When I click on the textview, the `SelectionChanged` event of `ListView` is not fired.

Is there a way to fire that, so that the `ListView` item is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you have [not asked a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I think I understand your problem. I'm assuming that when you said `textview`, you actually meant `Textbox` and that your problem is that your `ListViewItem` is not changed to the item that contains the `TextBox` that you clicked on. If this is so, then adding this `Style` should do the trick:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

While it looks strange, the second part is to ensure that the item remains selected after it loses `KeyboardFocus`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, but at a guess, you haven't handled the event:

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="MyEventHandler" ...
</ListView>
```